# Copying or cloning an HTML element in Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, copy, drop-down-menu

I have two html select boxes where items are moved from left to right, now I want to change the behavior such that elements are copied from right to the left. I tried `Oject.clone(o)` and `.cloneNode(true)` with prototype library. It cause my browser to hang,

Presently the code that moves elements from left to right is as follows,

```
$('left').appendChild($('right').options.item($('right').selectedIndex));
```

How do I change this such that there is a copy of elements from left to right, instead of actual moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Object.clone()` use `Element.clone()`

```
var selected = $('right').options.item($('right').selectedIndex);
var copy = Element.clone(selected, true);
$('left').appendChild(copy);
```

Documentation: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/clone/